# Retrying failed calls to a crypto exchange

Tags: f#

This code represents logic used to retry failed calls to a crypto exchange:

```
let retries =
    [
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.)
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3.)
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.)
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.)
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30.)
    ]


let rec retryAsync (retryAttempts: TimeSpan list) (request: unit -> Async<Result<'a, ExchangeError>>) : Async<Result<'a, ExchangeError>> =
    async {
        let! r = request()
        match r with
        | Result.Ok x ->
            return Result.Ok x
        | Result.Error e ->
            match e with
            | ExchangeError.HttpError _
            | ExchangeError.ServiceUnavailable
            | ExchangeError.InvalidTimestamp ->
                match retryAttempts with
                | [] ->
                    return Result.Error e
                | h::t ->
                    Thread.Sleep(h)
                    return! retryAsync t request
            | _ ->
                return Result.Error e
    }
```

The logic is as follow:
There are a bunch of functions that return Async<Result<'a, ExchangeError>> and perform various external operations.

I am wrapping them in this code where results that return ok will be passed through, and results that return error will go through some more scrutiny.
Some errors trigger a retry (HttpError, ServiceUnavailable and InvalidTimestamp) since they are transient errors which are not linked to the request itself. Other errors are not going through a retry and are passed through directly.

I would like to know if this could be expressed in a more concise / "understandable right away by a 3rd party" way.

It can be used that way:

```
// cancel orders
let cancelOrdersAsync (exchange: IExchange) instrument (orderIds: string list) : Async<Result<unit, ExchangeError>> =
    exchange.CancelOrdersAsync(instrument, orderIds)

// cancel orders and retry
let cancelOrdersRetryAsync (exchange: IExchange) instrument (orderIds: string list) =
    retryAsync retries (fun _ -> cancelOrdersAsync exchange instrument orderIds)
```

as an extra question: could this be made as a curried function where I'd just have something like *retryAsync retries cancelOrders*

Comment: I don't have enough to add to make this a full answer, but as a beginner to `f#` I find this code easily understandable without your explanation.  If your goal is to make this understandable to someone who doesn't know even basic `f#`, then I would issue a frame challenge to say that's not really a desirable goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks understandable to me, here's a couple possible improvements:

`retryInterval` is more informative than `retries` (you could also specify that these are the defaults):

```fs
let defaultRetryIntervals =
    [
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.)
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3.)
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.)
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.)
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30.)
    ]
```

`retryAsync` could be made a little more general, while also clarifying what exactly it's meant to handle (just the retry logic) - we can also reduce a match nesting level:

```fs
let rec retry<'a>
    (shouldRetry: 'a -> bool)
    (retryIntervals: TimeSpan list)
    (request: unit -> Async<'a>)
        : Async<'a>
    =
    async {
        let! result = request()
        match shouldRetry result, retryIntervals with
        | true, head::rest ->
            Thread.Sleep(head)
            return! retry shouldRetry rest request
        | false, _
        | _, [] ->
            return result
    }
```

And the equivalent to your `retryAsync` becomes:

```fs
let shouldRetryExchange =
    function
    | Result.Error (ExchangeError.HttpError _)
    | Result.Error ExchangeError.ServiceUnavailable
    | Result.Error ExchangeError.InvalidTimestamp ->
        true
    | _ ->
        false

let retryExchange<'ok> = retry<Result<'ok,_>> shouldRetryExchange
```

> as an extra question: could this be made as a curried function where I'd just have something like retryAsync retries cancelOrders

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8379346) an answer from Tomas Petricek on that. You'd need to create (tupled) single-argument versions of your api functions:

```fs
let cancelOrdersAsync'
    (
        exchange: IExchange,
        instrument,
        orderIds: string list
    ) =
    cancelOrdersAsync exchange instrument orderIds
```

and then modify `retry` to get a curried `cancelOrdersRetryAsync`:

```fs
let rec retryArg<'a, 'arg>
    (shouldRetry: 'a -> bool)
    (retryIntervals: TimeSpan list)
    (request: 'arg -> Async<'a>)
    arg
        : Async<'a>
    =
    async {
        let! result = request arg
        ... same as before ...
    }

let cancelOrdersRetryAsync =
    retryArg shouldRetryExchange defaultRetryIntervals cancelOrdersAsync'
```